# How can I make my column contents display beside each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the contents of my bootstrap columns to be beside each other and look like my intended layout below. I tried using different CSS to display inline etc, and I could not get it to look like this.

This is how it looks like now: [image: Current layout], and what I want it to look like.[image: My intended layout]

I can change the pictures later, but for now i want the picture, header, paragraph and the button to display like in my new intended version. Thank you for the help!

```
<div class="col-md-6"><a href="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/downloads/#tab2"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1286" src="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2015/04/extensionsOnGithub.png" alt="extensionsOnGithub" width="230" /></a>

<h2>Predictive Analytics Extensions</h2>
<br>
You can add new features in IBM SPSS Modeler and SPSS Statistics using the IBM Predictive Extensions. There are more than 200 extensions available! If you want, you can also create your own extensions. We built a nice catalog so you can find them easily.

<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GET EXTENSIONS</button>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6">

<a href="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/downloads/#tab2"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1286" src="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2015/04/extensionsOnGithub.png" alt="extensionsOnGithub" width="230" /></a></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>Predictive Analytics FixPacks</h2>
<br>
Keep your software up-to-date with maintainance updates available to all supported customers.

<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">SEARCH FOR FIXPACKS</button>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- The easiest solution is to add a minimum height on the paragraph text. This will not work with larger texts or resizing of the window.
- Not as nice is to read the 2 heights with JS and modify the smallest height to the largest.
- The best solution but the most work is to add a padding bottom to the item container, add a position relative. Then make the buttons position absolute with a bottom 0 style.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12268/)

```
<div class="row article-container">
<div class="col-md-6 article"><a href="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/downloads/#tab2"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1286" src="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2015/04/extensionsOnGithub.png" alt="extensionsOnGithub" width="230" /></a>


<h2>Predictive Analytics Extensions</h2>

    <p>You can add new features in IBM SPSS Modeler and SPSS Statistics using the IBM Predictive Extensions. There are more than 200 extensions available! If you want, you can also create your own extensions. We built a nice catalog so you can find them easily.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GET EXTENSIONS</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 article">
<a href="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/downloads/#tab2"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1286" src="http://localhost/predictiveanalytics/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2015/04/extensionsOnGithub.png" alt="extensionsOnGithub" width="230" /></a><h2>Predictive Analytics FixPacks</h2><p>Keep your software up-to-date with maintainance updates available to all supported customers.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">SEARCH FOR FIXPACKS</button>
</div>
```

```
.article-container {
 position: relative;
}

.article {
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 height: 100%;
 position: initial;

}
button{
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

Do add a media query to ignore the button css for small screens

Comment: Hi, how do I float the image to the left?

Comment: I fixed the fiddle link, the image is already on the left, why do you want it to float? Are you gonna add more images next to each other?

Comment: if the answer is correct please mark it as the answer.